# Fit images in box based on min and height values

Tags: javascript, image-scaling

The title might not be the best, but let me explain. I have a minimum height value of **50px** and a maximum of **612px**. Then I have a large amount of images that has to fit in a box with a height of **800px** and a dynamic width.

The trick is that each image has a value, we can call it **likes**. What I want to do is that the image with most "likes" should get the size of 612px and the image with least "likes" should get the height of 50px. The rest of the images should size accordingly to their amount of "likes" against the min and max values. All images are square sized.

I can't get the math together. Hope you guys can help :)

Example HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <article class="item" data-likes="500"><img src="foo.jpg"></article>
  <article class="item" data-likes="100"><img src="bar.jpg"></article>
  <article class="item" data-likes="350"><img src="baz.jpg"></article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (assuming all images source files are `612 x 612` in the first place ...) :

```
img_size = 50 + Math.round( (612-50)*((img_likes-min_likes)/(max_likes-min_likes)) );
img_size *= 800/612;
```

Comment: Should be Math.round. That almost works, two things are missing. it doesn't care about the container height and the max image height

Comment: Yeah I thought so, no problem :)

Comment: You need the 612px images to fit the 800px container, and the smaller ones to keep proportionality against that container, that's what you are asking for ?

Comment: Hm, I need all images to fit into the container. But I realize that's another problem. The math from your side works. Thank you!